# Trying to solve 2y"+y'=0 through power series and running into some issues.

Tags: power-series

2y"+y'=0 has a solution in the form c1+c2(e^-x/2)

Through power series, I got [image]

The official solution does not include my factored x for the Maclaurin of (e^-x/2). How did I go wrong? Or do I incorporate the extra x differently?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio they are applying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method but hiding the crucial steps.

Comment: I love the crucial steps.

Comment: Well write them please (not in comments; rather inside your post).

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question. Here are some tips. Your mistake was in the Taylor series for $e^x$. You should always check what the limits of a sum are before applying a standard summation formula. Also, the power of each $x$ term should be exactly equal to the factorial argument in the denominator, i.e., try converting $\frac{x^n}{n+1}$ terms into $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ terms before applying the formula.

Comment: Of course! the OP did not deign to write the main part, to derive the 3rd line from the 2nd one (find the recurrence relation on the $a_n$'s induced by the differential equation). + mistaken penultimate line, as noted below by Amogh.

Answer (score 1):

The second to last line should be:
$$y=a_0+a_1x\left(1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{24}-\frac{x^3}{192}+\frac{x^4}{1920}\cdots\right)$$
Using summation notation:
$$y=a_0+a_1x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n(-1)^n}{2^n(n+1)!}$$
Multiplying the $x$ into the summation:
$$y=a_0+a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}(-1)^n}{2^n(n+1)!}$$
$$y=a_0+a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{-1}\frac{x^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}$$
$$y=a_0-2a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
Since the summation starts at $n+1=1$ and not $n+1=0$:
$$y=a_0-2a_1\left(e^{-\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^0}{0!}\right)$$
$$y=a_0+2a_1-2a_1e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$
Since $a_0+2a_1$ and $-2a_1$ are just arbitrary constants:
$$y=c_1+c_2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$

Comment: We should not answer "poor quality posts" like this one: no effort to improve the question by adding the requested details. If the poster had accepted to do that, they probably would have found their mistake. Please don't do for them the work they are able to. This is not the role of this site.

Comment: @AnneBauval Alright, I'll make sure to follow that next time.

Comment: You can do it also this time: you can delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you bro @Amogh. Don't mind the rude people, your help is always welcome :)